# Wrap a Cell with New Line in Cell and then separate out the line within the cell by a delimiter

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Good afternoon:

I am trying to figure out a way to wrap a cell in Excel and then separate out the line within the cell by a delimiter.

Example:

[image]

From A1 to A2.  A2 represents the finished product.

I want to use > as the delimiter to separate the string and then have it lined up.  Currently this can be done by moving the cursor to the > and clicking ALT ENTER to separate the string, which is seen in the screen shot.

I would like to know if there is a function or formula that can be used to automate the process.

Comment: Try `=mid(Substitute(A1,"<",Char(10) & "<"),2,999)

Comment: and don't forget to set the cell to "wrap"

Comment: what function can I use if I wanted to bring back only from the string, name="Pep", basically name="   "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment, which I had not tested, use this formula:

```
=MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"<",CHAR(10) & "<"),2,999)
```

[image]